# Does the Inception Model have two softmax outputs?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, softmax

The Inception v3 model is shown in this image:

[image: Inception v3 Model]

The image is from this blog-post:

https://research.googleblog.com/2016/03/train-your-own-image-classifier-with.html

It seems that there are two Softmax classification outputs. Why is that?

Which one is used in the TensorFlow example as the output tensor with the name 'softmax:0' in this file?

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py

The academic paper for the Inception v3 model doesn't seem to have this image of the Inception model:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567v3.pdf

I'm trying to understand why there are these two branches of the network with seemingly two different softmax-outputs.

Thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 4 of the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567v3.pdf) you cite is about *auxiliary classifiers*. These are classifiers added to the lower levels of the network, that improve training by mitigating the vanishing gradients problem and speedup convergence. For running inference on a trained network, you should use the main classifier, called `softmax:0` in the model, and **NOT** the auxiliary classifier, called `auxiliary_softmax:0`.

Comment: I had read section 4 in that paper just prior to asking the question and did wonder if that was the explanation. But I got the impression from section 4 that it wasn't very useful so I assumed it wasn't included in the Inception model. Thanks for clearing it up!