# difference between losses/clone_0/softmax_cross_entropy_loss and losses/clone_0/aux_loss/value

Tags: tensorflow

What is the difference between losses/clone_0/softmax_cross_entropy_loss and losses/clone_0/aux_loss/value in inception-v4?
Currently, I'm training a large-scale model using tf-slim and inception-v4 network on 4 GPUs(--num_clones=4 ). but these two charts are completely different. after 190K steps with batch-size=128, I get these charts:[Losses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eppZQ.png)

as you can see in the image total loss and have a similar trend. but the softmax_cross_entropy have a completely different procedure!
Which one of these losses can describe the training procedure better?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the first, main one. You can read about the auxiliary head and its loss in here [Does the Inception Model have two softmax outputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352108/does-the-inception-model-have-two-softmax-outputs)

This aux_loss is defined here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/4bd29ac0ba1004d7393b7d029b05257dffd5cbe6/inception/inception/inception_model.py#L135